# How to restart application devise gem ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.  I have installed the devise gem and created a User model using the steps indicated here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Now after:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

It indicates in the steps that:

You should restart your application after changing Devise's configuration options. Otherwise, you will run into strange errors, for example, users being unable to login and route helpers being undefined.

This may be a bit of a dumb question but does anybody know what they mean by restarting the application.  I think it means that I have to restart the server but I just want to make sure I don't run into problems down the road.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by "*restart your application*" they do mean to *restart the server* on which your Rails application is currently running provided its already running else you just need to start the server. Devise recommends restarting your application to load configurations(like initializer) or new files(like views), etc which are loaded when rails server is started.

You could read about `rails server` command in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-server)

On a side note, restarting the server is more likely to solve some of the problems(or at least highlight them). Just go ahead and restart the server.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks